# cant compile app on phone gap - new error with depriciation

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I get the below errors in phonegap build. this is even when building an old version of the app that used to work. not understanding the error, any help??

### Build Date: 2018-05-25 16:11:42 +0000

### PLUGIN OUTPUT

Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" at "3.0.0" for android
Fetching plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin@^2.3.1" via npm
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" at "2.4.1" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.3.3" for android

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@^2.4.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "2.4.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.0.0" via npm

### Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android

### COMPILE OUTPUT

:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_3icce6xsgr7rsvstratajpe9b.run(/project/build.gradle:138)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
:prepareAndroidArchCoreRuntime110Library
:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleLivedataCore110Library
:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleRuntime110Library
:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleViewmodel110Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2711Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42711Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBaseLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasementLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocationLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1201Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasksLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommonLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIidLicense1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1201Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessagingLicense1201Library
:prepareComOnesignalOneSignal391Library
:prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib623ReleaseLibrary
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResourcesERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.249 secs
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

Answer (score 0):

In your `platforms/android` folder that contains the `build.gradle` file, create another file called `build-extras.gradle` and put the following inside of it:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.  I also had to update `AndroidManifest.xml` to point to the correct icon folder because it changed that config variable to the `mipmap` folders instead of the `drawable` folders.

Comment: We are using phone gap we dont have a build.grade file

Comment: @rrjlt phonegap creates one for you when you add the android platform.  From your root of your phonegap project there should be a `platforms/android` folder

Answer (score 0):

Set your compileSdkVersion to 23 in your module's build.gradle file and  see

Comment: We are using phone gap we dont have a build.grade file

Comment: Do you have platforms folder in you Project root file?